# Reuse Mongoose schema in client code

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, meanjs

I'm developing a MEANJS application and have defined a Mongoose schema. Now I would like to reuse that in the client code to validate forms with [Mongoose in the browser](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html).

The basic application was generated using `yo meanjs` and I have a file containing the model as follows:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schemaDefinition = { ... };
var schemaOptions = { ... };

var EventSchema = new Schema(schemaDefinition, schemaOptions);

mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

What is the best way, to include that schema in the client to reuse it for form validation?

Comment: The answer is write in the documentation. Either globally by including it in a script tag, or using a tool like browserify or webpack.

Comment: @RobertMoskal The documentation says so about the mongoose funcationality, but not its schema.

Comment: That's all you get on the client, the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You may assign [validators directly to your schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html). I assume that Mongoose prototype cannot be render on the client side, moreover it needs lots of work to map it against Angular's way-of-validating models. 
Furthermore is a lack of security validating only on the client side.

It's quite easy to use AJAX call from your Angular application serialise your model and parse it to your Express listener.
Since your schema has validators, no malformed data will be parsed into your collection.

Comment: Validating on the client is much more user-friendly and faster, that is why I would like to do it there *as well*. Validation on the server would not be skipped at all.